# can't get word wrap to work on UIButton

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a simple UIButton and try to get word wrap but it always shows the text in one line exceeding the button size.

```
 NSString * text = NSLocalizedString(@"Start Loading",@"Start Loading");
_continueBtn.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
_continueBtn.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[_continueBtn setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Also in UI builder when I set word wrap there the text wraps - only when I run the app the text appears in one line.

What have I missed here?

Comment: I've updated my answer - I've tried the same code, that you've post, and it's working good. On what version of iOS you're running this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
_continueBtn.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

I've tried next code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 70, 50);
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[button setTitle:@"start loading"
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

It's working good for me:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Commenting here, because I have not enough reputation to comment the question.
@user387184 What about creating label and adding it to button? That should work.

Comment: Yes - but this is really not a preferred solution :-)

Comment: please don't ask me why  - but suddenly it worked - maybe because I did a clean and deleted derived data ????

Comment: From now on I gonna delete derived data before posting questions to the stackoverflow :)
Actually, I'm trying to clean projects when I'm changing resources and getting some strange errors. But I've never thought that cleaning derived data can fix them too.